# I need to use join fetch, but it leads to "query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list"

Tags: sql, jpql

I have the following query:

```
@Query("SELECT new de.projectemployee.ProjectEmployee(employee) " +
       "FROM ProjectEmployee projectEmployee JOIN FETCH projectEmployee.employee employee " +
       "WHERE projectEmployee.project.id = :id")
List<ProjectEmployee> findInOneRequestByProjectId(@Param("id") long id);
```

And I get the following error:

> org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list

As many solutions suggest, I can replace `JOIN FETCH` with `JOIN`. But the problem with this solution is that it leads to n+1 requests. Is there another way to fix the error?

Comment: What you're doing makes no sense. `select a from A a left join fetch a.b` means: return me As and fetch their Bs in the same query so that wen I call a.getBs() on the result, an additional query isn't needed. But your query doesn't select As. It only select Bs. Why do you think a fetch is needed? What are the n+1 requests you're concerned about?

Comment: I log the SQL statements, and there are N queries to resolve the employee if N is the size of the returned list

Comment: There are N queries when executing **which** code? And **what** are the queries? Seeing N queries and randomly adding a "fetch" in a query is not the right way to solve the issue. The code and the queries matter in order to analyze what the actual problem is, and how best to solve it.

Answer (score -3):

Fetch is used to populate lazy load field in object, it has no use here. Just remove FETCH from your query and it will work.